# my yaml script is not working in raspberrypi

Tags: ansible

I have a script that is working correctly on my Mac and other linux boxes.  I moved it over to a raspberrypi and I am getting a error.  At first I thought it was a syntax error and again, I copied my script over and it appears to be working correctly on other devices.

I am using the latest version of ansible and raspbian.  Also I have installed the pivmomi plugin. 
FYI:  on my script I have removed the variables for obvious reasons.

Any suggestions?

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/root/theScript.yaml': line 27, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
- name: "Gather info about the vmware guest vm"
  ^ here
```

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  #become: yes
  ignore_unreachable: true

  vars:
  tasks:

  - name: "Gather info about the vmware guest vm"
    vmware_guest_info:
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
      datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
      validate_certs: no
      name: "{{ guest_name }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: vm_info
```

Comment: What is the command you executed? Run command with -vv to get verbose logging. Most times the error means what it exactly saying. Maybe the module vmware_guest_info.py is not actually present in the directory it is looking for? Verbose logging will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the raspberry repo does not have the latest version of ansible.  Once I updated it my script worked.

I used the link below to update ansible.

https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/installing-ansible-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like an indentation error to me. How did you copy and paste this in. Could there be tabs interpreted here.  Try removing lines 3,4 5 6 and 8.